Any difference between "one's lower back" AND "the small of one's back"?

He approached me from behind and he touched the small of my back.

"the small of one's back", which I had never heard, has just reminded of another word for the same part of the body, which is "one's lower back".
I checked google ngram, and compared which one is used more often. And suprisingly "the small of my/his/her back" seems to be being used more than "my lower back".
But when it comes to "your/our/their back", it becomes the opposite. I mean "your/our/their lower back" seems to be used more often than "the small of your/our/their back".
Is it really so amongst native english speakers?

The small of one's back is smaller and narrower than one's lower back. It is a specific region of the lower back near the spine just above the pelvis. Your kidneys are near your lower back, but they're too far to the sides to be near the small of the back. Hip pain could be felt in the lower back, but that might be too low to be considered the small of the back.
Both phrases are used, but have different meanings and uses. The small of one's back indicates a more specific area than the lower back. Anatomy aside, it has a minor connotation of intimacy or familiarity - in a romance novel you'd likely find someone touching the small of someone's back rather than their lower back.

+1 for the romance-novel example.   "He caressed her lumbar region" wouldn't cut it  :-)
